# Smoke Domain and Divisions

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am using Blender 2.79c with Cycles Render.  I opened a new scene and then added under the objects tab. “Quick Smoke” using the Cycles Render. I worked just fine when played in the timeline.  I then opened the Physics Tab and under Smoke Modifier I use the Domain tab and set my Resolution to 90. Then if I use or click on the Flow Tab and go back to the Domain Tab all my setting changes back to the default. I tired it about six times and it does the same thing every time. Is this suppose to happen?  Does changing from Domain to Flow and back to Domain suppose to change the settings back to the default settings?

Seems very strange to me but then I am still in the learning stage. Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to select the flow object and change the settings for flow there. An object cannot be domain and flow object at the same time.

Comment: Good to know thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Smoke Domain and Smoke Flow Objects have to be different objects. An object cannot be Domain and Flow.

To change the settings for Flow, select the flow object and then modify the flow settings.

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/introduction.html):

> At least a [Domain object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html) and one [Flow object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html) are required to create a smoke simulation.
>
> A basic workflow looks like this:
>
> Create a [Domain object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html) that defines the bounds of the simulation volume.
>
> Define a [Flow object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html) or objects which will emit smoke and fire.
>
> Set [Collision objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/collision.html) to make the smoke interact with objects in the scene.
>
> Assign a [Volumetric material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/material.html) to the domain object.
>
> Save the blend-file.
>
> [Bake](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/baking.html) the simulation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. There is so much to learn in Blender. I will keep plugging away at it.